# Create [serial-port] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I currently work quite a bit with serial ports in C# and have asked a question pertaining to them. I don't know if the usage would be there to warrant it, but it would be nice to have a [serial-port](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-port) tag for future questions. I don't have the rep, so could someone else create the tag?

For reference, there are [3,542 questions tagged with [serial-port] on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/serial-port). It's not an obscure or uncommon tag.

Comment: Is there a specific question on here that needs the tag?  Tags can only be created through new or existing questions.

Comment: @Jamal Here are two: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31483/serialport-c-class and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29807/better-approach-to-using-the-c-serialport-class

Comment: Okay, it's done.